# can all in the network connected in one terminal?to make run commands to all

Tags: command-line, networking, ssh, gnome-terminal, xterm

is there a way to take a one terminal connected to all networks?

i say im running in a network with 60 PC and im using xtrem and Other way is Open-SSH to run a same commands to all pc 1 by 1 is there a other way to connect all network pc in one terminal so that when a give commands it runs all to PC with just a one terminal open?

Comment: Do you know of Python Paramiko? http://www.paramiko.org/ It's not what you asked for but I think it can help you.

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for something like `clusterssh`, `cssh`, `pssh`, or even `terminator`

Tools like [cssh](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/clusterssh/) may use some inventory files, which could be handy defining aliases identifying group of targets.

Others such as [terminator](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/terminator/) are more suited for everyday use, while would allow you to split a terminal into multiple consoles, and eventually broadcast to groups, ...